# Is this translation from Ancient Greek correct?

Tags: greek, christianity, greek-translation

I'd like to ask experts in Greek to verify a translation from this mosaic from Jerash

[image: Mosaic fragment]

This one is a cropped and rotated version of [an original image from here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Jarash_-_4140195717.jpg)

English translation:

> Lord the God *the* Holy *of* Kosmas and *of* Damianos. Have mercy on the way *(path)* of Dagisteon *(Dagisteos)* and receive this offering.

Thank you.

**Update:**

Thanks to @Alessio I've managed to reach the [book](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=wu.89058842857;view=1up;seq=288;size=150) which has this iscription commented on page 246. The authors call **Dagistheus** mentioned above as "one of Justinian's less successful generals".

Comment: Tribunus, the title has a wide range, as the Wikipedia article shows in the opening sentence, The Latin dictionary(Smith) says it can mean chieftain, too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your translation is close!

Here is a letter for letter transcription of the image, except there is a line over "ΘΣ" in the second line:

```
      ΚΥΡΙΕ
    ΟΘΣΤΟΥΑΓΙȢ
  ΚΟΣΜΑϏΔΑΜΙΑΝΟὙ
ΕΛΕΗΣΟΝΤΟΝΤΡΙΒΟΥΝΟΝ
  ΔΑΓΙΣΘΕΟΝΚΑΙΠΡΟΣ
    ΔΕΞΕΤΗΝΑΥΤΟΥ
      ΠΡΟΣΦΟ
       ΡΑΝ
```

This is:

> Κύριε ὁ θ(εὸ)ς τοῦ ἁγίου Κοσμᾶ κ(αὶ) Δαμιανοῦ, ἐλέησον τὸν τριβοῦνον Δαγίσθεον καὶ πρόσδεξε τὴν αὐτοῦ προσφοράν.

The translation becomes straightforward now:

> O Lord, God of saint[s] Cosmas and Damian, have mercy on the tribune Dagistheos and receive his offering.

A few notes:

1. As noted in the comments, "πρόσδεξε" is probably a form of "προσδέξαι." This form is attested in later Greek, particularly in the Middle East.
2. "ΘΣ" (with a line) is an abbreviation for "θεὸς"
3. "Ȣ" is a ligature for "ου"
4. "Ϗ" alone is an abbreviation for "καὶ" (not abbreviated consistently, for spacing reasons)
5. The author uses a so-called "lunate sigma" (like our "C")

Comment: Three minutes later than you; trying to track Dagis or Dagistheos the tribune's name.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Especially for transcripting from Uncial, "ou" ligature and Kai conjunction.
I supposed προσδέξε is προσδέξει (as in <https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%B4%CE%AD%CF%87%CE%BF%CE%BC%CE%B1%CE%B9 >). I know that last _iota_ was often shortened to subscript. And after all, this is not a manuscript but a mosaic which could allow for more simplifications. Does this make sense?

Comment: "δέξει" as in the future 2nd person singular? It seems strange to say "You will receive his gift"

Comment: If you want to use the real character in your answer, here it is, so you can copy and paste: `U+03F9 ‹Ϲ› \N{GREEK CAPITAL LUNATE SIGMA SYMBOL}`

Comment: I decided that Dagistheos was definitely a proper name when found _Bath of Dagistheos_ mentioned in this book https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=ycf9fopn6V8C

Comment: I'm guessing you're right that ΠΡΟΣΔΕΞΕ is for impv. πρόσδεξαι, since αι merged into ε in Koine.

Comment: For completeness, you could find the text of this inscription here: http://epigraphy.packhum.org/text/305238?hs=200-209, from C.H. Kraeling, *Gerasa: City of the Decapolis. An Account Embodying the Record of a Joint Excavation Conducted by Yale University and the British School of Archaeology in Jerusalem (1928-1930), and Yale University and the American Schools of Oriental Research (1930-1931, 1933-1934)*, New Haven [Conn.] 1938, n. 311.

Comment: @TKR you're right in guessing that it must be intended as πρόσδεξαι. Please note that πρόσδεξε is only attested in later imperial and Byzantine times, mainly in Arabia and Palestina: http://epigraphy.packhum.org/search?patt=%CF%80%CF%81%CE%BF%CF%83%CE%B4%CE%B5%CE%BE%CE%B5%CE%BE%CE%B5

Comment: @Alessio, thanks for a link to a great resource. I was able to find other inscriptions from the same bigger image there. Do you know if the site or the book itself holds some kind of translation or comments to these inscriptions? Cheers.

Comment: @Alessio Thank you for the references and edit: extremely helpful!

Answer (score 7):

> ┼
>   KYPIE
>   OΘΣTOYAΓΙΟΥ
>   ΚΟCΜΑ·Κ·ΔΑΜΙΑΝΟΥ
>   ΕΛΕΗΣΟΝΤΡΙΒΟΥΝΟΝ
>   ΔΑΓΙΣΘΕΟΝΚΑΙΠΡΟΣ
>   ΔΕΞΕΤΗΝΑΥΤΟΥ
>   ΠΡΟΣΦΟ
>   ΡΑΝ
>   Ξ

The symbol at the end of line two is a (genitive) OY digraph.  The 'K' as you show is KAI.  TPIBOYNON is probably the loan word Tribunus from Latin; the long 'u' has been transliterated as 'ou'.

> ┼  KYPIE O ΘEOΣ TOY AΓΙΟΥ ΚΟCΜΑ·ΚAI·ΔΑΜΙΑΝΟΥ  ΕΛΕΗΣΟΝ ΤΡΙΒΟΥΝΟΝ
>   ΔΑΓΙΣΘΕΟΝ ΚΑΙ ΠΡΟΣΔΕΞΕΤΗΝ ΑΥΤΟΥ ΠΡΟΣΦΟΡΑΝ Ξ

O Lord, the God of Saint Cosmas and Damian, have mercy on Tribune Dagistheon, and accept his offering. Ξ

Comment: Great answer--I think you're right that it's a ξ, not a χ: any idea why it's not προσδέξαι?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Especially for the hint on tribunus from Latin. Did you mean this kind of [Tribune] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tribune) ? If we assume it was build in the end of 3rd - beginning of 4th century AD, does it make sense for this context?

Comment: @brianpck The loanword Tribounon, and the Genitive Kosma from Cosmas and the Name Dagistheos (Dagon is God?) suggest a polyglot, multiracial, mixed culture.  IMO  prosdexe sounds like a Latin imperative, or less probably a Greek active aorist pl. imperative ending, tacked onto the Greek verb stem "graciously receive."

Comment: Such loanwords were actually very common in the Byzantine empire, and I don't see anything outlandish with leaving a foreign name undeclined: Jerash was almost definitely polyglot, but not with Latin. It was introduced to Greek with the conquest of Alexander the Great. I would be pretty surprised if this was hybrid "Latin-Greek" speak, especially since in all likelihood this area did not speak Latin at all.

Comment: @Hugh I think TKR is on the right track in his comment to my answer, that this is a result of Koine pronunciation.